# hdparm secure erase with progress updates?

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, utilities, hdparm

Does anyone know of a clever way to receive any sort of progress status updates using hdparm secure erase?

Ideally the end result would be something like dd's status=progress attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Just a FYI, the hdparm program isn't doing the erase, but telling the drive to start the erase. The drive acts autonomously from there. It would be up to the drive to report it's progress, not hdparm.